# Discord.js v14 get server name

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I’m trying to get the name of the discord server that a message was sent in (discord.js). This is my code:

```
client.guilds.cache.get()
```

In the message it says `undefined` instead of the servers name. Please help!

Comment: Stop trying to guess properties, look at the documentation instead (https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/Client?scrollTo=guilds). If you have the guild object you can use `guild.name`. However, you'll need to access a specific guild through `client.guilds.cache`, via `.find()` or `.get()`

Comment: @Elitezen You are just rude and telling me that i should stop trying and go read the docs. I came here for a reason and that was because I didn't get any help from the documentation. Thanks for the code but it didn't work. Is this how you want it to be? `client.guilds.cache.get(guild.name)`

Comment: I did not mean to come off rude, there's no other way to say "stop guessing properties." The documentation will always have what you need, it's up to you to know how to read through it.

Comment: We also don't have as much information about your problem. What information about your specific guild do you have? If you have the ID you can do `client.guilds.cache.get(ID).name` assuming it's cached. Otherwise fetch the guild

Comment: Thanks, @Elitezen . Sorry for misunderstanding your answer. I'm not looking to find a specific server by its ID. I want to get the server name from where the command is sent. Do you understand, or should I explain in another way?

Comment: If It's a slash command: `interaction.guild.name`, for a message command: `message.guild.name` iirc

Comment: @Elitezen it is giving me an error saying that `guild` Is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.forEach` to do the same thing for every guild your client is in.

```js
client.guilds.cache.forEach( (guild) => {
console.log(`${guild.name} | ${guild.memberCount} | ${guild.id}`)
})
```

Comment: Thanks! I saw similar questions like this but it was not what I was looking for… Thank you anyway!